# ¿Como darle limite a un JTextField en Java?

Tags: java

Hay muchas interrogante sobre el uso de estas funciones y eventos aquí aclaro las dudas. No obstante hay muchas formas de lograr esta limitación.

Answer (score 1):

La forma para darle una restricción de caracteres por ejemplo a un DNI o RUT en un JTextField vendría así:

```
public  void maxdni(KeyEvent e, JTextField txtDni, int longitud){
    if (txtDni.getText().length() >= longitud) 
        e.consume();
}

protected void keyTypedTxtDni(KeyEvent arg0) {
    maxdni(arg0, txtDni, 8);  

}
```

Tengo dos funciones sin retorno que me validaran la cantidad de caracteres que deba ingresar. Los eventos KeyTyped y KeyEvent me permite asignar el tamaño y JTextField elegido, con la función .consume() borrara todo los demás caracteres ingresados.

Answer (score 0):

También puedes utilizar expresiones regulares, por ejemplo para un dni puedes utilizar:

```
String regex = "\\d{8}[A-HJ-NP-TV-Z]";
```

Se utilizar tambien `Pattern.matches(regex, dni)` que devuelve true o false dependiendo de si el dni que se le introduce como segundo parámetro cumple con la expresión regular que se le pasa como primer parámetro.